# Unable to submit form using admin post wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I have been facing a problem in wordpress. I have a form as below

```
<form role="form" action="<?php echo admin_url( 'admin-post.php' ); ?>" method="post">
   <div class="form-group">
          <input type="text" class="form-control required" name="input_name" id="inputName" placeholder="Name*"/>
   </div>
   <div class="form-group">
          <input type="email" class="form-control required" name="input_email" id="inputEmail" placeholder="Email*"/>
          $nonce = wp_create_nonce( 'catalog_nonce' );
          <input type="hidden" name="catalog_nonce" value="<?php echo $nonce?>"/>
           <input type="hidden" name="action" value="download_catalog"/>
   </div>
   <div class="form-group">
           <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputMobile" name="input_mobile" placeholder="Mobile"/>
    </div>
</form>
```

And i have added the admin post hook in my functions.php as

```
add_action('admin_post_download_catalog','download_catalog');
add_action('admin_post_nopriv_download_catalog','download_catalog');
function download_catalog() {
   print_r($_POST);wp_die();
}
```

But every time I submit the form it redirects to search results page.

I have also tested by updating the permalink and also deactivating plugins. Nothing happened it redirects to `domain/home/s?=` . Please help me . Thanks in advance

Comment: It is not so easy to create submit form for admin side. 1st you need to add NONCE field, without nonce it just can't work. Then you need to read some tutorial about "How to create front-end submit post for WordPress".

Comment: I have done almost all the things in tutorials. But I am unable to find what is reason for this problem

Comment: what about nonces? The first thing tutorials teach is "nonce". But you haven't added it

Comment: sorry i forgot to update the question see now I have added nonce but no luck.

Comment: can you tell what is your final purpose with this code? what do you want to do?

Comment: quote for downloading catalogs

Comment: clearing cookies solved the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Clearing cookies in the browser fixed the issue.

Comment: Jings who would've thought. After many attempts, this worked for me too! thanks.